# Understanding selenium web-elements list

Tags: python, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Ok so I had a list of web items created by seleniums Webdriver.find_elements_by_path method, and I had trouble utilizing the data. 
Ultimately, the code I needed to get what I wanted was this:

```
menu_items=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@role="menuitem"]')[-2]
```

I was only ever able to get any meaningful data here by using a negative index. If I used any positive indices, the menu_items would return nothing.

However, when I had left menu_items as follows:

```
menu_items=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@role="menuitem"]')
```

I could iterate through the list and gain access to the webelements properly, meaning if I had"for i in menu_items" I could call something like i.text and have the desired result. But again, I could not do menu_items[2]. I am new to selenium so if someone could explain what is going on here, that would be very helpful

Comment: _I could not do menu_items[2]_ What do you mean you "couldn't"?  What happened when you tried?  Did you get an error?

Comment: Check the size of the list by using  `print(len(menu_items))` whether it is more than 2.

Comment: When I tried printing menu_items[2] I was returned an empty list, it wasn't an error but not at all what I was expecting given the for loop displayed web elements with their corresponding session and element ids

Comment: There were 9 elements in the list, and even if it were a sizing issue I would have recieved an index out of range error

Comment: My guess is that some/many of the elements that were returned are invisible or otherwise not interactable. You probably need to refine your locator to only show the ones you want... the visible ones, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code...

```
menu_items=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@role="menuitem"]')[-2]
```

...indicates you are considering the second element counting from the **right** instead of the **left** as `list[-1]` refers to the last element within the list and `list[-2]` refers to the second last element in the list.

A bit more about your usecase would have helped us to construct a canonical answer. The number of visible/interactable elements at any given point of time and/or the sequence in which the elements gets visible/interactable may vary based on the type of elements present in the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes). Incase the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) consists of [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/), [Angular](https://angular.io/), [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/), enabled elements even the position of the elements may differ as well.